# How to put location information into photo and uploading into facebook using android facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, graph, photo

I am looking at posting Photo with only latitude and longitude only. I tried both 
- bundle.putString("location","\"latitude\":"+latitude+",\"longitude\":"+longitude);
- bundle.putString("coordinates","\"latitude\":"+latitude+",\"longitude\":"+longitude);

both return success but no location information display in the photo in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Snippet for Adding Location :

```
            try {
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
                coordinates.put("latitude", "Your Latitude");
                coordinates.put("longitude", "Your Longitude");
                params.putString("coordinates", coordinates.toString());
                params.putString("Message", "Bla Bla Bla");

                // Do your stuffs for Post
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I still have no success.. the post return success with no latitude and longitude information.